# Why do I get a timeout error when sending WebRequest from a .Net Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I am using a `HttpWebRequest` object retrieve data from an external api. Initially I used a standard .Net console app to do this, and everything worked fine. Now, I am converting it to a .Net Core app, and I am getting timeout errors when sending the web request to the same URL, and using the same data in the header. Here is the snippet of code that sends the request:

```
        var url = "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension?perPage=500";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

This works fine both locally and on my Azure server in a traditional .Net console app. But when using this same snippet of code inside my new .Net Core app, it runs fine locally, but when running on my Azure server, it hangs on this line:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
```

And then I get an error that says:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage --->
>   System.Net.WebException: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond

Is there something within the .Net Core framework that could be blocking this request from going out? What am I missing here?

Comment: The request consists of http headers and the headers from you application have to be accepted by the host for the connection to work. The console application is adding some default headers that are missing in your application.   So I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the working Net console and compare with non working headers.

Comment: By "Azure Server" do you mean the online, cloud ready "Azure"? If so, do you have firewall restrictions on your Azure configuration thats preventing the connection? You normally have to configure it to accept requests

Comment: Yes, it's the cloud-ready Azure server. This particular code runs inside a web job. Also, this is an outbound connection. My web job is attempting to hit a third-party api. It works fine when running inside a web job that is NOT .Net Core (on the same server instance).

Comment: @MattSpinks I've the same problem with Azure and .NET Core. Do you have resolved the issue?

Comment: Hi @markzzz, I did. Turns out it was port exhaustion. My web server runs other processes simultaneously with their own outbound connections. it was getting overloaded. However, one thing that did really help was to turn off "ARR affinity" on my web service. I didn't realize what that did. With that setting "on", when I scaled out my app, it still only used a single instance to handle requests. So scaling out did not make much of a difference. However, when I turned "ARR Affinity" to "off", when I scaled my app out, it handled much better with these outbound requests.